# Вылезают элементы за пределы блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Такая проблема, делаю верстку на флексбокс, а элементы вылезают за пределы блока, как это исправить?

Вот код:

```css
.header {
 background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000;
 padding-top: 40px;
}

.header::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

.header__navigation {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: red;
}

.header__logo {
 font-family: 'Wisdom-Script';
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #fed136;
}

.header__menu {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
 <div class="container">
  <nav class="header__navigation">
   <a href="#" class="header__logo">
    Golden
   </a>
   <ul class="header__menu">
    <li class="header__menu-item">
     <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">
      Home
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header__menu-item">
     <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">
      Services
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header__menu-item">
     <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">
      Portfolio
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header__menu-item">
     <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">
      About
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="header__menu-item">
     <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">
      Contact
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="header__offer">
   <div class="title">
    Welcome To Our Studio
   </div>
   <h1>
    it's nice to meet you
   </h1>
   <a href="#" class="btn">
    Tell Me More
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Можно конкретнее какие элементы вылезают за какой блок?

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно было убрать полосу прокрутки и оставить `padding` для `header`-a

```css
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* Уберу все отступы чтобы было красиво(хотя бы немного) */
.header {
 background: url(../img/header-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000;
 background: gray;
 padding-top: 40px;
 /* Убрал полосу прокрутки */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* .header::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1000;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
 */
.header__navigation {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background: red;
}

.header__logo {
 font-family: 'Wisdom-Script';
 font-size: 26px;
 color: #fed136;
}

.header__menu {
 /* Убрал точки списков */
 list-style: none;
 /* Добавил расстояние между ссылками */
 justify-content: space-around;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 /* Дал .header__menu немного места чтобы он мог "дышать" */
 width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="header__navigation">
            <a href="#" class="header__logo">Golden
   </a>
            <ul class="header__menu">
                <li class="header__menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">Home
     </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">Services
     </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">Portfolio
     </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">About
     </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header__menu-item">
                    <a href="#" class="header__menu-link">Contact
     </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header__offer">
            <div class="title">Welcome To Our Studio
   </div>
            <h1>it's nice to meet you
   </h1>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Tell Me More
   </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно тебя понял, то проблема с этим, изображение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наезжают друг на друга. В твоей задаче недостаточно конкретики. Но, если я правильно понял, то вот решение, прописываешь в CSS:

```
li.header__menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
li.header__menu-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```